# Only one entry in No-SQL database needs encrypting

Tags: encryption

So I have the document format as follows:

```
{
    id : plaintext,
    date-created : plaintext,
    data : binary
}
```

The data entry needs encrypting and decrypting. My idea was to have a private key, and use subsequest hashes of the id and date created (which will never change) to form a unique password for each document. Is this worth doing, or is it just wasted effort?

For what it's worth, the server uses Python.

Comment: Please clarify what the scenario is. If you have a key, why use hashes of the ID to form a unique password? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It would be a way to have each user have a different key.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you store, manage, and use that secret key. (You meant "secret" key, not "private" key, I assume. If it's locked in a secure file, that's about all you can do short of having a hardware security module.

But it's still close to security through obscurity. If an attacker has all the time in the world to explore your systems, is a trusted insider, or if it's a commercial product, he will find out how to become an admin, access your key and decrypt it. But if it's a snatch and grab crime of opportunity, you might get lucky because he may not bother to grab "encrypted" data, or know where to find the key. So in that sense it reduces a small bit of risk. These days, I'd take that over storing plaintext.

Just know that it's not perfect security, and it shouldn't be your only defense.